# How to add a wallet to your geth account list

Tags: go-ethereum, accounts, myetherwallet

I just created a new account on myetherwallet.com and installed geth on windows. 
I opened cmd and typed in 'cd/' and typed 'geth account list'.

In return, I got a warning saying there's no etherbase set and no accounts found as default.

Naturally, I wanted to add my existing account to the list.

So I typed 'geth account update 0x65E6ee5Eb448720E42D10542C5DE11eAaE5e384D'

Then it said

> no etherbase set and no accounts found as default
>   unlocking account 0x65E6ee5Eb448720E42D10542C5DE11eAaE5e384D | Attempt 1/3

I typed in the password I typed in on myetherwallet.com when I created my account.

In turn, it said

> 'Fatal : Failed to unlock account 0x65E6ee5Eb448720E42D10542C5DE11eAaE5e384D (no keyfor given address or file).

Not sure how to proceed from here... Any help?

Answer (score 1):

So you have 2 main options to replicate import the acccount you created on myEtherWallet.

**Using Private Key**

- Open notepad and paste the private key in it. Let's name the file as priv_key.txt
- Run the command:

  `geth account import <path_to_priv_key.txt>`
- You need to choose the password, your keystore file will be locked with.
- After successful import, delete the file priv_key.txt

**Using Keystore file**

- My Ether Wallet also provides the keystore file directly that you can import to geth
- Just move the keystore file keystore folder inside `%APPDATA%\Ethereum`. The password will be same as the one you provided in MEW.

Answer (score 0):

Try importing a keystore file with this command:
`geth account import <keyfile>`

You should have it from the registration of new wallet.